# Oracle MERGE from external data source

Tags: c#, oracle, merge, bulkinsert

I'm building a .NET application that talks to an Oracle 11g database.  I am trying to take data from Excel files provided by a third party and upsert (`UPDATE` record if exists, `INSERT` if not), but am having some trouble with performance.

These Excel files are to replace tariff codes and descriptions, so there are a couple thousand records in each file.

```
|   Tariff   |        Description        |
|----------------------------------------|
| 1234567890 | 'Sample description here' |
```

I did some research on bulk inserting, and even wrote a function that opens a transaction in the application, executes a bunch of `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements, then commits.  Unfortunately, that takes a long time and prolongs the session between the application and the database.

```
public void UpsertMultipleRecords(string[] updates, string[] inserts) {
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("connection string here");
    conn.Open();
    OleDbTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < updates.Length; i++) {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(updates[i], conn);
            cmd.Transaction = trans;
            int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (count < 1) {
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(inserts[i], conn);
                cmd.Transaction = trans;
            }
        }
        trans.Commit();
    } catch (OleDbException ex) {
        trans.Rollback();
    } finally {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I found via Ask Tom that an efficient way of doing something like this is using an Oracle `MERGE` statement, implemented in 9i. From what I understand, this is only possible using two existing tables in Oracle.  I've tried but don't understand temporary tables or if that's possible.  If I create a new table that just holds my data when I `MERGE`, I still need a solid way of bulk inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually upload my files to merge, is by first inserting into a load table with [sql*loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ) and then executing a merge statement from the load table into the target table.

A temporary table will only retain it's contents for the duration of the session. I expect sql*loader to end the session upon completion, so better use a normal table that you truncate after the merge.

```
merge into target_table t
using load_table l on (t.key = l.key) -- brackets are mandatory
when matched then update
set t.col = l.col
,   t.col2 = l.col2
,   t.col3 = l.col3
when not matched then insert
(t.key, t.col, t.col2, t.col3)
values
(l.key, l.col, l.col2, l.col3)
```

Comment: One problem: I would have to run sql*loader from a web application in order for this to be used repeatedly.  Is this possible?

Comment: It can be run from the command line, but the webserver should then also be the database server I guess. Not a good practice.
Probably better to use a .NET bulk insert.
A tip: If you have a lot of insert statements inside a BEGIN ... END; body, Oracle will treat it as a single statement and only parse it once. A lot faster.

Comment: Nice suggestion.  I ended up using this article for bulk inserting: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/BulkOperationsUsingOracleDataProviderForNETODPNET.aspx

I created a table to hold the data and used your `MERGE` statement.  It works really well.  Thanks!